# Accept only normal date in html form

Tags: html, forms, date

how can I do to accept only normal date (yyyy-mm-dd) in html form? I tried:

```
<input type="date" name="waznosci" min="2015-01-02"/>
```

but when I use it, I can write for example "2342424" and it's work. I want to work only yyyy-mm-dd. Anybody have some idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this by using HTML5 validation based on pattern attribute:

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}" class="datepicker" name="waznosci" value="" />
```

And as you commented you can use this pattern:

```
<input type="text" pattern="20[0-9][0-9]-((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))-(([1-2][0-9])|(3[0-1])|(0[1-9]))" class="datepicker" name="waznosci" value="" />
```

Comment: Thanks :) I change it to "20[0-9][0-9]-((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))-(([1-2][0-9])|(3[0-1])|(0[1-9]))" and works cool :D

Comment: @Mateusz:- Yes that would take the leap year also into consideration!

Comment: @Mateusz:- Updated that in my answer as well so that it may help others in future as well :)